# android app showing error (unfortunately,Sudoku has stopped)

Tags: java, android, xml

hello i am learning android from book hello,android and i am stuck in  chapter 3 .
I am trying to show a new activity containing information about Sudoku game when user click the about button
but dwe to a some reason when i ran the app it shows me unfortunately,Sudoku has stopped.I tried to solve by myself but unable to figure out the problem .I need your hellllllllllp 
here the files are listed below

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.android.sudoku.Sudoku"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".About"
        android:label="@string/about_title">
    </activity>

</application>
```

about.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dip"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/about_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/about_text"/>

</ScrollView>
```

activity_sudoku.xml(my main activity)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/background"
android:padding="30dip" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dip"
    android:text="@string/main_title"
    android:textSize="24.5sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/continue_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/continue_label" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/meow"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/new_game_label" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/about_button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/about_label" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/exit_button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/exit_label" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ext_button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/dialog_label" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Sudoku.java

```
package com.android.sudoku;

//import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
//import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
//import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
//import android.view.LayoutInflater;
//import android.view.Menu;
//import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.app.Activity;
//import android.view.View;
//import android.view.ViewGroup;
//import android.os.Build;

public class Sudoku extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sudoku);

        // setup click listeners for all the button
        View continueButton = findViewById(R.id.continue_button);
        continueButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        View newButton = findViewById(R.id.new_button);
        newButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        System.out.print("here ");
        View aboutButton = findViewById(R.id.about_button);
        aboutButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        System.out.println("no error");
        View exitButton = findViewById(R.id.exit_button);
        exitButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        View dialogButton = findViewById(R.id.ext_button);
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {

        }
    }


    public void onClick(View v)  {

        switch(v.getId()) {

        case R.id.about_button:
            Intent i = new Intent(this,About.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        // more buttons go here id any
        }

    }

}
```

About.java

```
package com.android.sudoku;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class About extends Activity {
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.about);
}
}
```

LogCat errors

```
12-21 08:03:36.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1415): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-21 08:03:36.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1415): Process: com.android.sudoku, PID: 1415
12-21 08:03:36.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1415): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.sudoku/com.android.sudoku.Sudoku}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-21 08:03:36.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
12-21 08:03:36.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
12-21 08:03:36.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
12-21 08:03:36.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
12-21 08:03:36.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-21 08:03:36.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-21 08:03:36.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
12-21 08:03:36.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-21 08:03:36.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-21 08:03:36.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
12-21 08:03:36.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
12-21 08:03:36.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-21 08:03:36.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1415): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-21 08:03:36.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at com.android.sudoku.Sudoku.onCreate(Sudoku.java:30)
12-21 08:03:36.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
12-21 08:03:36.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
12-21 08:03:36.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
12-21 08:03:36.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     ... 11 more
12-21 08:03:42.062: I/Process(1415): Sending signal. PID: 1415 SIG: 9
12-21 08:04:17.702: D/AndroidRuntime(1455): Shutting down VM
12-21 08:04:17.702: W/dalvikvm(1455): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2af0ba8)
12-21 08:04:17.732: E/AndroidRuntime(1455): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-21 08:04:17.732: E/AndroidRuntime(1455): Process: com.android.sudoku, PID: 1455
12-21 08:04:17.732: E/AndroidRuntime(1455): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.sudoku/com.android.sudoku.Sudoku}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-21 08:04:17.732: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
12-21 08:04:17.732: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
12-21 08:04:17.732: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
12-21 08:04:17.732: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
12-21 08:04:17.732: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-21 08:04:17.732: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-21 08:04:17.732: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
12-21 08:04:17.732: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-21 08:04:17.732: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-21 08:04:17.732: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
12-21 08:04:17.732: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
12-21 08:04:17.732: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-21 08:04:17.732: E/AndroidRuntime(1455): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-21 08:04:17.732: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at com.android.sudoku.Sudoku.onCreate(Sudoku.java:30)
12-21 08:04:17.732: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
12-21 08:04:17.732: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
12-21 08:04:17.732: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
12-21 08:04:17.732: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     ... 11 more
12-21 08:04:21.882: I/Process(1455): Sending signal. PID: 1455 SIG: 9
```

Comment: @ShivankSagar please post logical error

Comment: @shayanpourvatan ow god i just confused with names.sorry i deleted my comment

Comment: this is launching error ...means you have not defined any of your `textview` or `button`(or any layout) in the xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see a view with id `new_button` in your layout. Therefore `findViewById(R.id.new_button)` returns `null` and invoking a method on the null causes the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of :

```
View newButton = findViewById(R.id.new_button);
```

use this :

```
Button newButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.new_button);
```

Comment: thank you very very much i did not have any id named new_button i replace it with my id(meow) and it works once again thanks